# How can I pass props through an anchor tag?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I want to know, how can I pass props to other component? Something like `objectid={top.id}` through an anchor tag.

```
{lists.map((top) => {
       return (
            <li key={id}>
               <a href={'/object/'+ slugify(top.title) } objectid={top.id}>
                 <img alt={top.title} src={top.image-url}/>
               </a>
            </li>
       )})
}
```

I want to pass {top.id} to the component which will be rendered on going to url from href given and there I can access it like `props.objectid`

Comment: What you did seems right. What does `top` contain? What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: On the component which is pointed through that href. when I try to console.log(props.objectid) it shows undefined

Comment: For the image, you cannot have `src={top.image-url}`. You need to use `src={top["image-url"]}` else it won't work. Check out my answer @zinx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the image, you cannot have `src={top.image-url}`. You need to use `src={top["image-url"]}` else it won't work.

And if you're using [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/), please use the [React Router: `Link`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) component for this.

```js
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/object/${slugify(top.title)}`,
    state: { objectId: top.id }
  }}
>
  <img alt={top.title} src={top["image-url"]} />
</Link>
```

Here you can also set the `Link` state, so that it can be accessible in the other page too, so as from which page this has come from, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have no issue with img tag because top is from a JSON response which have image-url as its object

Comment: @zinx You have to use `top["image-url"]` and not `top.image-url`. That's another problem I am talking about. And this way, in the new page, you can get the `objectId` as the value of `top.id` when you clicked it.

Comment: and If I try to use LINK I get New Error ...Let me solve that then I will accept your answer If it solves my current problem

Comment: Thank you , now I can get objectId in rendered component and I also changed the img src as you suggested top["image-url"] Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) `Link`

```
  <Link to={{
     pathname: `/object/${slugify(top.title)}`,
     state: top.id  
  }} objectid={top.id}>
   <img alt={top.title} src={top.image-url}/>
  </Link>
```

Comment: why would yo do something like this with object id

Comment: For the image, you cannot have `src={top.image-url}`. You need to use `src={top["image-url"]}` else it won't work. Check out my answer @zinx